# passing parameter from WebMethod to Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I have the following WebMethod :-

```
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void OpenReport(string reportName)
    {
        Report report = reportsBll.GetReports().FirstOrDefault(x => reportQuestion != null && x.Id == reportQuestion.ReportId);

        if (report != null) reportUrl = report.Url;
    }
```

Now I wish to pass the report.Url to this Jquery Method :-

```
    $('.ReportButton').click(function () {
    var args = { reportName : '' };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ReportsByQuestionsDetails.aspx/OpenReport",
        data: JSON.stringify(args),
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            document.location.href = reportUrl;
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

How can I pass the reportUrl from the WebMethod to the Jquery?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Are you aware of what the `void` keyword in your c# method means?

Comment: Yes I have to change it to return the URL, however I have no idea on how to pass it to Jquery

Comment: Try checking the value of `data` in your jQuery success function after changing your webmethod.

Comment: I tried to check the value of data, its object Object

Comment: Do `console.log(data)`, not an alert.

Comment: I did console.log(data).  Where do I see the results?  At the moment I am getting a redirect to http://localhost/myapp/[object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your page method to actually return something, you currently have it returning nothing via the `void` return type, change it to this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string OpenReport(string reportName)
{
    Report report = reportsBll.GetReports().FirstOrDefault(x => reportQuestion != null && x.Id == reportQuestion.ReportId);

    if (report != null)
    { 
        return report.Url;
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

UPDATE: Microsoft added a parent container for JSON responses in ASP.NET AJAX 3.5 in an effort to combat potential cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks; therefore you `success` callback needs to be this:

```
success: function (data) {
    alert('success');
    document.location.href = data.d;
}
```

There are ways to mitigate this as described in [Never worry about ASP.NET AJAX’s .d again](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/)

Comment: You still return nothing if `report`  is null.

Comment: @Johann - your `success` callback needs to change its logic to use `document.location.href = data;` instead of `document.location.href = reportUrl;`. `data` is what you returned from the page method, in this case a `string`.

Comment: Karl yes at the moment its document.location.href = data; Still not working though

Comment: Then your `reportsBll.GetReports()` is returning invalid data for the `URL`, did you debug it to see what the value of the `URL` is?

Comment: I am definelty getting the Url, I just debugged.  Its redirecting to this page http://localhost/myapp/[object Object]

Comment: @Johann - Try `document.location.href = data.d;`.

Comment: and I have my url as follows ~/webpage.aspx.  How can I display that? In normal aspx I use Page.ResolveUrl.  How can I do that in jquery?

Comment: Resolve the URL to its full path on the server and then return the full path as the `string` value. Read [ResolveUrl() without Page](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Sep/18/ResolveUrl-without-Page), because you do not have a `Page` instance while in an ASP.NET AJAX page method.

Comment: ok cool KArl. Any idea how I can resolve the ~/ in the URL?  I tried                 location.href = '<%= ResolveUrl(data.d) %>'; but that does not work

Comment: ok Karl thanks, the problem is that since the WebMethod is static, I cannot call the Page.ResolveUrl

Comment: @Johann - do the resolution in the page method and return the full path as a string, I posted a reference, in a comment, to how you can resolve a URL without the actual `Page` object, because `ResolveUrl` is a method of the `Page` class and that `Page` class is unavailable in ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods, the name is a bit of a misnomer.

Comment: @Johann - no problem, sorry this was such a back and forth; that `.d` is a nuisance. Good luck to you.

Comment: @KarlAnderson do you mind having a look at my question too please, giving me a headache.. here's the link. thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758029/how-do-i-pass-parameters-from-jquery-to-asp-net-webmethod/27758103?noredirect=1#comment43927787_27758103

Answer (score 5):

You need to **return** the `string` in your C# method:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string OpenReport(string reportName)
{
    string reportUrl = string.Empty;
    Report report = reportsBll.GetReports().FirstOrDefault(x => reportQuestion != null && x.Id == reportQuestion.ReportId);

    if (report != null) reportUrl = report.Url;

    return reportUrl;
}
```

Then in your ajax return Url you can do (you might want a fallback for when the report is null however):

```
success: function (data) {
    location.href = data;
},
```

Comment: @Johann If you debug the `WebMethod`, does the breakpoint hit? Is the report **definitely** not null?

Comment: yes i am getting a url, just debugged.  Redirecting to http://localhost/myapp/[object Object]

Comment: @Johann is there anything in `data.d` in your `success` method? Try alerting it. If so, use that.