# How do i pass parameters from JQuery to ASP.NET webmethod?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, webmethod

I have written this jQuery ajax method below which calls a webmethod. The call happens fine except the parameter which is a User object has empty fields. I can see the values in firebug when i debug but they do not get through to the User object parameter in the webmethod

There are two values i am trying to pass from the my jQuery method to the Webmethod which are "UserID" (Guid) and "About" (string) which are both properties of the User class, but on the service end, the User object is just empty. Please help me identify whatever i am missing. Thank you ... See code below.

**JQuery**

```
function updatePersonalProfile(userId) {
var user = {};
user.UserID = userId;
var updatedPersonalProfile = $(".txtPersonalProfile").html();
user.About = updatedPersonalProfile;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PresentationService.asmx/updateUserPersonalProfile",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{user:" + JSON.stringify(user) + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(response) {
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
}
```

***Webmethod***

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void UpdateUserPersonalProfile(User user)
    {
        if (null == portfolioService)
        {
            portfolioService = new PortfolioService();
        }
        portfolioService.updateUserPersonalProfile(user);
    }
```

Comment: @KarlAnderson do you mind looking at this for me please. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured what i was doing wrong, both fields have private setter in the Domain object. therefore jQuery cant set the properties.

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the single quotes in user when defining data. Please change data line with the code shown below:

```
data: "{'user':" + JSON.stringify(user) + "}",
```

Comment: I have debugged it in the web browser, and those variables do have the right values, its just not coming through on the webmethod parameter for some reason... could this be something else? as i have tried changing the way that data line is written

Comment: Please specify the web service, browser and Jquery version you are using. Also, typically I do not specify ResponseFormat in the WS method and success in the Jquery AJAX call. Could you try again without ScriptMethod defined in the WS method and success in the AJAX call?

Comment: Also notice that the url value is case sensitive, thus the valueyou should use is 'PresentationService.asmx/UpdateUserPersonalProfile'